# Facebook - How to add Like button inside a Static FBML?

Tags: facebook, fbml

Has anyone here tried to add a Like button on a static FBML (a fan page)???

Not sure if this is possible by simply embedding the Like button plugin on to the static FBML, but I tried the iframe version and it didn't show up...

Any ideas how to integrate???

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I added one to a normal website using the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and the [Like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) using the fb:like element.  I imagine you can do that to a fan page as well.